# Como adicionar reference no visual studio

Tags: .net, team-foundation-server, nuget

Na empresa temos um problema com algumas references doprojeto, pois as mesmas estão em pastas diferentes nas máquinas de cada programador e normalmente quando se faz check-in e de seguida get latest version, todos ficamos com problemas nas referidas references. E todos temos que as adicionar de novo.

A minha pergunta é se existe alguma possibilidade de alocar essas reference em algum sitio da team foundation server ou no nuget management ou se existe outro tipo de solução para este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas referências são os frameworks corporativos ou bibliotecas que as empresas criam e deixar elas nas máquinas dos desenvolvedores em paths's fixos é a pior maneira de lidar com elas.

**Gestão de componentes**

Para .Net existe uma solução bastante elegante para componentes server-side: Nuget.

O Nuget é servidor de pacotes, é possível que ele já seja do seu conhecimento, através do site Nuget.org. O interessante é que não é necessário expor os pacotes através do site público, já que é possível ter um repositório privado de pacotes na empresa.

Pode-se começar criando uma pasta na rede com share para os desenvolvedores, e colocar os pacotes lá, com a extensão *nupkg*. Ou usar uma aplicação servidora, com portal, muito parecido com o site público e até mesmo com features que vão de autenticação até feeds para outros tipos de pacote. O Proget tem uma versão para uso comecial gratuíta e depois versões pagas com as features avançadas. Existem também outros servidores, tipo Myget, etc...

**Configurar um repositório Nuget no Visual Studio**

Para configurar um servidor nuget, Proget, por exemplo, ou mesmo uma pasta, como feed no Visual Studio, acesse o menu Tools > Options.

Na janela clique no campo *Search Options* e digite Nuget (1), clique em menu *Package Sources* (2), clique no botão com o sinal de + (3), dê um nome (4), e no campo *Source* coloque o endereço do feed (5) e clique em *Update* (6).
É interessante colocar como primeira opção, então com ele selecionado, clique na seta que aponta para cima (7), assim quando for buscar um pacote, será dado prioridade ao servidor interno de Nuget.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que neste exemplo eu coloquei uma pasta compartilhada na rede, que terá os arquivos .nupkg. Se usar um servidor, o *Source* deverá ser um endereço de feed RSS.

Comment: Então o melhor que poderei tentar fazer para resolver esta situação será criar uma pasta partilhada pela rede onde se colocará estas bibliotecas externas e todos os developers apontam as referências no projeto para essa pasta?

Comment: Não entenda isso como uma pasta compartilhada, por que quando você cadastra no VS, é como se fosse um feed
E sim, usar Nuget vai ser o melhor que você pode fazer para gesta da componentização na sua aplicação

Comment: É possível criar tipo um repositório no Nuget das minhas libs? Para que desta forma todos possam ir lá buscar as libs e adicionar no projeto.

Comment: Sim a ideia é essa! Cria essa pasta é coloca os seus pacotes Nuget lá

Comment: E criando essa pasta onde a coloco para ficar visível a toda a team, é essa parte que não estou a perceber.

Comment: Complementei a resposta, veja se está claro agora

Comment: A sua resposta está espectacular e me ajudou imenso. Muito Obrigado